# style a ListView as a standard ContextMenu

Tags: android, coding-style, contextmenu

I am wondering where the default ContextMenu style is defined... to copy/use it!

I have few ListView in my app, using the provided TexView layout android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1. My listings are looking odd (black background) compare to the default ones like the ContextMenu (white background).

So if you know where it is, or how to make my ListView having a "standard" style, I would be glad to know about it ;)

Thanks
jo

Comment: I finaly made my own style, replaced default menu & context listings by my own Dialog/listings, using the same style. Everything appears uniform now. But I didn't find the original styling rules..!

Comment: jowbwat, can you show me how to do it?

Comment: nope, no clue! it's been a while man. Pretty sure all those classes have evolved quite a lot now - was using Android 2.something at the time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Context Menus look identical to the regular Options Menu. And those menu items are setup with a layout found at:

> `$(SDK_ROOT)/platforms/android-$(API_LEVEL)/data/res/layout/menu_item.xml`.